# Как вывести время без сдвига временной зоны

Tags: java

Как вывести время без сдвига по временной зоне?

А точнее что бы вывод был, в данном случае, 00:00:10

```
DateFormat HOURS_MIN_SEC = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(10000);
System.out.println(HOURS_MIN_SEC.format(calendar.getTime())); >> 03:00:10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateFormat HOURS_MIN_SEC = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
HOURS_MIN_SEC.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(10000);
System.out.println(HOURS_MIN_SEC.format(calendar.getTime()));
```